# finding total no of rows in the textbox

Tags: javascript

how can i get the no. of rows in the multilines textbox through javascript function if some body inserted many no of text in that textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/uqavo3/2

```
var nums_of_rows = countLines( 'textarea_id');

    function countLines(areaId){
      var theArea = document.getElementById(areaId);
      var theLines = theArea.value.replace((new RegExp(".{"+theArea.cols+"}","g")),"\n").split("\n");
      if(theLines[theLines.length-1]=="") 
      theLines.length--;
      return theLines.length;
    }​

<textarea cols="#" rows="#" id="">some text here</textarea>
```

Comment: If the last line of the row is a hard newline, it will double count it.

Answer (score 2):

```
textBox.value.split("\n").length
```

Comment: No, it's the DOM element.  You can get it with `getElementById`.

Comment: This will only work for <ENTER>. If the text auto-wraps this will not work!

Comment: It will return the number of hard lines (from enter).